# Default Windows Dialog Browsing does not show “My Computer” nor “Drives”

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The problem is, for some strange reason, all of a sudden, whenever I can "browse" within Eclipse(Java IDE) for a file/project, or whatever it is, the default window that is being shown does not contain any drives on my computer, and only a Desktop plus my user's windows folder. It is shown below:

[image]

As you clearly see, there is no way to go to the "My Computer" or any drive. I have a workaround (for now), but it will become pretty irritating fast, so I'm looking for a solution that caused all this. The workaround anyway, is typing the "C:\" or any drive letter, and hitting Browse button afterwards. If I do this, all is back to normal:

[image]

Anybody encountered same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank God, the internet. After searching for almost 2 hours for this, I got lucky and found this thread:

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19411_102-412058/browse-for-folder-missing-computer-and-libraries/

Well, when you have 16GB of RAM, 2 monitors, and 2 SSD drives (for some of you it might not be much, but for me it is), you kinda tend to loose yourself into thinking how "powerful" your machine is ;).

The answer was just like for the user in the above thread. I did have a lot of items on my desktop, that increased today. Seems at one point today I "crossed" the magical line, which broke the "Browse Dialog".

In anyway, posting here, if someone else will run into this issue in the future. I hope it will be helpful to someone.